# How to get the absolute path of project files in eclipse using plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-api

I am trying to create a plugin which would give me a list of absolute path of all the files inside a project opened in eclipse.

I tried but I am able to get the path of the active window only..

My action code is:

```
  IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart(); 
    IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
    if (file == null)
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    String path = file.getRawLocation().toOSString();
    System.out.println("path: " + path);
```

Here I am only getting the path for active window..But I want list of absolute path of all the files inside a project ..mainly the files under src folder...

Please guide me if I can do it in the same way or do I need to use some different API for this.

Comment: +1, Even I was looking for the same, and was about to post in SO :)

Comment: Try this to iterate through files and folders : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744434/6699913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744434/6699913)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After my research, I found out below code would get the path of Eclipse's current workspace's project directory:

```
//get object which represents the workspace  
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();  

//get location of workspace (java.io.File)  
File workspaceDirectory = workspace.getRoot().getLocation().toFile()
```

**Note:** You need to import `org.eclipse.core.resources` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` to use these API's

[Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/453807/vc/find-Workspace-Java-code-Eclipse)

Comment: thanx for the inception dude..but I want to access all the files in the src folder and get their absolute paths..can i iterate through the workspace directory by some means...

Comment: It's not worked for me, my project probably not in workspace

Answer (score 0):

Given an `IResource`, you can use the method `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.getLocation()` that returns an `IPath` with the "absolute path of this resource in the local file system, or null if no path can be determined". Then you can use the method `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath.toOSString()` that returns a String representation.