# Recursively list all files in eclipse workspace programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am getting workspace by calling `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()`.

How I can list all files(IFile) recursively in the workspace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root, projects and folders in a workspace all implement the `IContainer` interface.

Call `IContainer.members()` to get all the resources in the container.

Something like:

```java
void processContainer(IContainer container) throws CoreException
{
   IResource [] members = container.members();
   for (IResource member : members)
    {
       if (member instanceof IContainer)
         processContainer((IContainer)member);
       else if (member instanceof IFile)
         processFile((IFile)member);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I specify a directory level for a search? For example if I want to search for files only at this level:
`project\folder` not in levels lower like `project\folder\trash`

Comment: @2c00L You could add a 'depth' parameter to `processContainer`  and stop when you get to the required depth.