# IWorkspace search for file type

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to search my project workspace and find a certain type of files (e.g. `.txt`) and store them in a list for example.

I can access the workspace by:

```java
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
```

But how to search through the different folders and get the type of files that I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744012/recursively-list-all-files-in-eclipse-workspace-programmatically) you'll find your answer.

Basically you need to recursively parse every `IContainer` (with `members()` method) and search in them the file you want