# How to catch a moment when Eclipse is creating a new project?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a CDT plug-in for Eclipse IDE. I want to write to a project-scoped preference file when creating a project or just store an info to identify this project later and write to a file. How can I seize a moment when Eclipse is creating a new project and store some info about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `IResourceChangeListener` listener to listen for all resource changes:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

The listener implements the single method:

```java
public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event)
```

From the event you get the resource delta:

```java
IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();
```

The delta `getKind()` method will be `IResourceData.ADDED` for a new resource.

The delta has a `getResource` method which will get you the resource - you are interested in an `IProject`.

Note: Deltas can contain nested entries. You may have to use the `getAffectedChildren()` method of the delta to find the project, or use the `accept` method to visit all the nodes in the delta.

Comment: Greg-449, checked your solution, my listener was notified only about the workspace root changes when creating a new project, it suits me bad, I can store a set with already existing projects instances and use your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744012/recursively-list-all-files-in-eclipse-workspace-programmatically to retrieve all of the projects from the workspace root, but it will take a linear time to find the new project and, moreover, workspace's change does not always mean that a new project appeared.

Comment: Greg-449, I added a listener in the Plugin's start() in this way:
  `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(new ResourceChangeListener());`

Comment: You may need to look at the children of the top level delta or use the `accept` method to visit all resources in the delta. Added note to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Greg-449, thank you for your answer it works properly, but I have notifications too late to write to the preferences file, it is already locked by that moment. Do you have any idea of what can I do with this?

Comment: You probably need to use something based on `WorkspaceJob` to run your code after the currently update is complete and everything is unlocked again.