# How to refresh a view when it opens in RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

i'm developing a rcp application and i just need to refresh my view's data.

My view opens when user clicks the main toolbar item. Also my view has some data taken from the source code of user's project. When user change the source and open again the view, the view have to change(because of project source has been changed). 
How can i do this?

Comment: If you are asking how to listen for changes to files in the workspace look at `IResourceChangeListener`. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39516062/2670892)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view can register to be notified of part changes using `IPartService#addPartListener(IPartListener)`.  You can update on `partBroughtToTop()`.